# ActionBar styling different tab background when below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Is there a way to define `ActionBar` tab style so that it would have different backgrounds when tabs are in `ActionBar` and below it?

I can't seem to find a way to do that with theme configuration with these properties

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar.TabView</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar.TabText</item>
```

I can define tab background to be white in `@style/Custom.ActionBar.TabBar`. All is ok with `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`.
But when I switch to `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` it is placed inside `ActionBar` and it also becomes white. And thats is unwanted behavior.

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)."

So, ActionBar will not work for your target environment which is at API level 10 (Android 2.3.3).

Just in case, if you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity.

Hope this helps...

Comment: In my case I was only missing `<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/stacked_background</item>`property in my ActionBar style